# Multiple OS's on Multiple Drives bootloader

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader

I've seen a lot of similar threads, but nothing that I can understand.

I'm installing Linux Mint. I've installed Debian and Mint a couple of times and still can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

I've got Windows 10 on a 128 GB SSD, and I have a 1 TB SSD for other stuff, and I have a 256 GB HDD that I've got Linux on.

Whenever I boot into the HDD where grub is, Windows doesn't show up. There is only Linux. I can still boot to Windows by just choosing the SSD from the boot menu at startup, but I want to be able to just let my PC boot and be able to choose the OS.

So I'm reinstalling Linux Mint for like the third time here and I'm wondering which partition do I need to put the bootloader so that I can access either one from grub.

Do I need to put it where the Windows 10 loader is?

Or do I just need to put it on the primary partition of the SSD that has Windows?

I've been putting in on the HDD doesn't seem to have the desired effect. Anyway I've got no clue.

Answer (score 0):

For windows to appear when installing grub it must be fully shut down. You need to disable the hybrid mode shut down so that grub can mount the partition to see what is on it, Windows. If it is not, then grub cant mount it to check and won't create an entry because it doesn't know whats there. [--How to disable hybrid boot--](https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-hybrid-boot-and-shutdown-in-windows-8/)

As for what drive to place grub on, it should be on the first disk that is checked for a bootloader. Probably SATA0 or 1 or something on your motherboard, you would have to look it up. Without looking, I'd place it on the drive windows is on and overwrite windows' bootloader. That's most likely the first one checked for a bootloader. If you need to recover it later, just put in a windows cd and do startup repair.

Do these answer your questions? If not, please let me know and I can clarify.

Comment: Ok, so I had hibernate disabled so it took me a minute to figure out the fast startup thing, but I had already installed mint on my HDD just to be safe. I tried the full shut down then booted my hdd, ran grub, it didn't pick up windows. And yea my ssd with windows boots first. So if I reinstall mint you're saying to put it on the system reserved partition where the windows 10 loader currently is? (of the 128gb ssd)

Comment: Yes, overwrite the windows bootloader. It shouldn't have to go into a system reserved partition, it will write to the first 512 sectors of your hard drive, or 2048 if you use uefi, I believe those are the numbers for uefi at least. So, it won't overwrite your partitions. Just select the disk that you have windows on for the bootloader, probably sda if its the first bootable disk. Once into linux, there are grub commands you can use to pick windows back up and add it to your boot menu.